# Scroll to the top of the page after a sequence of divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

The code I have scrolls through a sequence of `divs`, each called `.container`. Each `.container` has a 100% height, so the user ends up quite far down the page as a result.

Now I am trying to scroll back to the top (using the same `.container` class) once the user reaches to the bottom of the page.

```
$('.down').click(function (e) {
    var next_container = $(this)
        .next(container);
    $('html, body')
        .animate({
        scrollTop: next_container.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Is there way for the jQuery to detect that the user is at the bottom of the document, and as a result, scroll to the first `.container` (rather than the next)?

Answer (score 0):

You can check that there is a next container found. If not, go to the first one:

```
$('.down').click(function (e) {
    var next_container = $(this).next(container);
    if (!next_container.length) {
        next_container  = $(container).first();
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: next_container.offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

This is assuming your `container` variable is a string with the selector of the element, ie. `".container"`

Comment: That's works for scrolling back to the top, however, the code no longer works in scrolling down? :(